# Android Emulator Screen Goes Blank After Pressing a Button

Tags: java, android, xml, emulation, manifest

I have created a small project in android, I have come to the point where after loading my app on the emulator, I press one of the buttons and it just shows a blank screen. I don't know why it is doing this. Any Help is welcome.

Here is my main Class:

```
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
     import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         
          Button Button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
          Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityList.class);
                    startActivity(i);
            }}
            );
          }
}
```

This is my XML Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sportsfitnessapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".ActivityList" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sportsfitnessapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I really need help. Thanks.

This is the Main XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/widget35"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".Screen1Activity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Menutxt"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Menu"
        android:textColor="#ffff0033"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Menutxt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Menutxt"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Choose_Activity"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:onClick="Button1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button5"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Graphical_Records"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Training_Schedule"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Weight_Tracker"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Heart_Rate_Monitor"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the ActivityList Class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ActivityList extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                setContentView(R.layout.activities_list);
                startActivity(i); 
            }
        {;
    }

}
```

This is the Activities List XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/widget0"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Treadmill"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Weights"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ActTxt"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Treadmill"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Aerobics"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Treadmill"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Treadmill"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Aerobic_Steps"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Cycling"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Aerobics"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Aerobics"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Cycling"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Swimming"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Cycling"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Cycling"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Swimming"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Rowing"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Swimming"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Swimming"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Rowing"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ActTxt"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Treadmill"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Activities"
    android:textColor="#ffff0033"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ETrainer"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Rowing"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Rowing"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Elliptical_Trainer"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Weights"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ETrainer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Free_Weights"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the `activity_main` layout.

Comment: @DeepakBala what for?... he said that he is able to click a button ... problem is in ActivityList class ...

Comment: You can remove activity_main layout, it's not needed.  Instead, post the XML for ActivityList as well as its code.  Also please post any errors in the logcat.

Comment: Some of the logcat Issues are: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented and this I think Flushing caches (mode 0)

Comment: Yeah I have that In my ActivtiesList Class

Comment: Yeah it does compiles

Comment: @Selvin Just checking if Button1 exists and that the button labtec clicked was not from another activity.

Comment: really doesn't matter ... in ActivityList @Labtec599 doesn't setting content view ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start a new activity, `ActivityList` by the code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityList.class);
startActivity(i);
```

And I am pretty sure you have not done:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_for_your_activity_list);
```

In your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

Example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list); 
}
```

---

Actually you have the code present but you need to move the line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activities_list);
```

up into

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

just like in the example I gave you.

And *please* follow convention.

```
Button Button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
```

should be:

```
Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_one);
```

Use indentation. And the ugliest one in `ActivityList`:

```
{;
}
```

Remove it at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activities_list);
}
```

use the above code in ActivityList

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are using any permissions or not. If yes, include them in your manifest file. For example -

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

I too had the same problem. This solution fixed it. Not only adding required permissions, but also check whether are there any serious warnings in your xml files, which also be reason for your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Yuo have assigned onClick listener for button1.OnClick of that you are starting new activity that is "ActivityList.class". So when you click on that button new activity will be created and contents in that activity will be displayed. If there is no contents in the "ActivityList"
empty screen will be displayed.

Comment: Well he did post his contents in the ActivityList